# Is Get Handwritten Text Operation Result of Computer Vision coginitve service of mircosoft stateful or stateless?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Ref : https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56f91f2d778daf23d8ec6739/operations/587f2cf1154055056008f201

This interface is used for getting handwritten text operation result. The URL to this interface should be retrieved from “Operation-Location” field returned from Recognize Handwritten Text interface.

This operation needs a operation Id by POST Recognize Handwritten Text api ,so it is stateful?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure why whether it's stateful or not is relevant to you, but the answer is clearly yes.  Note that the Operation ID is not valid after 48 hours, as noted [here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56f91f2d778daf23d8ec6739/operations/587f2c6a154055056008f200).